# Install metrics in sts

Tags: eclipse, plugins, metrics

I need to add Metrics plugin in  sts. I tried this : http://metrics.sourceforge.net/, but in vain.
There is any other way to do it?

when i try to install it to install it from the marketplace it occurs this problem 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2Ito.png)

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to ask/frame questions.

Comment: You can install [this metrics plug-ins via Eclipse Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/metrics) (_Help > Eclipse Marketplace..._). If you fail to install it, describe the steps to reproduce the problem and add the error message to your question (otherwise, it's hard to help you).

Comment: hello , i tried to install it from the market place .
Help > Eclipse Marketplace -> search metrics ->install ==> installation cannot be done as requested

Comment: i edited my question